# Domain of dependence in Causal structure for spacetimes that are not globally hyperbolic

Tags: general-relativity, causality

I'm trying to prove an implication of a surface $S$ embedded inside a manifold M not being its Cauchy surface. The literature and problems available for these topics are already pretty less hence I'm quite confused.
\
Suppose that the domain of dependence of S, $D(S) \neq M$. Then there exists $p \in M $ such that $p \notin D(S)$. By the definition of $D(S)$, this means that there exists some past inextendible causal curve through $p$ that does not intersect $S$. I now have to show that there exist curves that remain forever in $M - \overline{D(S)}$. The only way that occurs to me is contradiction. Assume that $\lambda$ is a curve that passes through $p$ and intersects $M-\overline{D(S)}$. I have to show that this cannot happen, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By definition of $D(S)$ at least following Wald, if $p \nin D(S)$